Flutter Web App - Demo App Fails to Load in Chrome
I am trying to connect the Flutter demo app to firebase. I have been trying to follow a few different tutorials for this, and when I include these lines
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

and run the app in chrome, I get a blank screen, as in the demo app never loads. Any ideas? I connected firebase to my app and copied the script into the index.html file, imported the firebase core package, added the dependency to the .yaml file, installed node js, and firebase login says I am already logged in

can you show the index.html config you made?and some browser logs

I just copied it directly from the firebase console and wrapped in the script tag, with the npm option selected

flutter_bootstrap.js:1
   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND


Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Access to internal resource at 'file:///C:/Development/Flutter/EIDOL/eidol/web/manifest.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, data, http, https, isolated-app.

those comments are the from the browser console
